# SAS data step programming

Tags: sas

I am new to SAS and I need some help here

The question below:
[image]

So far, I have done this:

```
data Purchase;

infile ‘c:\temp\PurchaseRecords.dat’ dlm=’,’ DSD;

input id $8 visit_no @ unitpurchased @;

keep id unitpurchased;

run;
```

What do I need to add in my statement to make those orders look like this?

just an example.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: SAS will not recognize smart quotes as you have posted. Ensure that those are not in your SAS program for starters.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.  This isn't answerable as posted.  To start with, please include all code, problem, and desired results as *text* in the post; you should not post images unless you're asking for help with graphics.  Second, please post a [MCVE] that works (with correct quotes etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `infile column=` in conjunction with the `input` held input `@` modifier to determine when held input has run past a trailing comma meant to indicate a missing value that is to be interpreted as a case of zero `units_purchased`.  The automatic variable `_infile_` is used to check when an input statement has positioned itself for the next read to be beyond the length of a data line.

```
data want;
  infile datalines dsd dlm=',' column=p;
  attrib id length=$8 units_purchased length=8 ;

  input id @; * held input record;

  * loop over held input record;
  do while (p <= length(_infile_)+1);  * +1 for dealing with trailing comma;

    input units_purchased @; * continue to hold the record;
    if missing(units_purchased) then units_purchased = 0;

    output;
  end;
datalines;
C005,3,15,,39
D2356,4,11,,5
A323,3,10,15,20
F123,1,
run;
```

The sometimes easier to use `@@` modifier wouldn't be used in this case because a missing value is to be considered valid input and thus can't be used to assert a 'no more data' condition.

Answer (score 0):

Since the data includes the number of values use that to control a DO loop to read the values.  I am not sure why you would want to lose the information on the order of the values, so I have commented out the KEEP statement.  To convert the missing values to zeros I used a sum statement. You could use an IF/THEN statement or a COALESE() function call or other methods to convert the missing values to zeros.

```
data Purchase;
  infile 'c:\temp\PurchaseRecords.dat' dsd truncover ;
  length id $8 ;
  input id visit_no @ ;
  do visit=1 to visit_no ;
    input unitpurchased @;
    unitpurchased+0;
    output;
  end;
  * keep id unitpurchased;
run;
```

Your original program had a few errors:

- Wrong quote characters. Use normal ASCII single or double quote characters.
- It is reading value of ID from only column 8.  I find it better to use `LENGTH` statement to define the variables instead of forcing SAS to guess at how to define the variables.
- The `input` statement improperly is trying to use column pointer motion command, `@nnn`. Plus the variable location to move the pointer to, `unitpurchased`, has not yet been given a value.
- No attempt was made to read more than one value from the line.
- You did not include `truncover` (or even the older `missover`) option on your `infile` statement.